# pytest how to use both getoption and parameterize

Tags: python, pytest

I have test which run subprocess on certain executable and test the stdout result.

So I use

```
#conftest.py
def pytest_addoption(parser):
    parser.addoption("--executable", action="store")


@pytest.fixture(scope="session", autouse=True)
def pass_executable(request):
    try:
        return request.config.getoption("--executable")
    except AttributeError:
        pass
```

So that I can use command line arg to set the pass the executable. I wish to use this as a global variable across all my tests. However, I have trouble with the tests which requires @pytest.mark.parametrize decorator. So my solution is to create a `test_update_path(pass_executable)` to update a global variable PATH, which works.

```
# test.py
PATH = 'defaultpath/app'


def test_update_path(pass_executable):
    global PATH 
    PATH = pass_executable
    print("Gloabl path is update to: ")
    print(PATH)

def test_1():
    # This will work 
    print("Now next")
    print(PATH)
    cmd = [PATH]
    stdout, stderr = run_subprocess(cmd)
    assert stdout == 'some expected result'


@pytest.mark.parametrize("args", [1, 2, 3])
def test_2(path, args):
    print("Now next")
    print(PATH)
    cmd = paramparser(PATH, args)
    stdout, stderr = run_subprocess(cmd)
    assert stdout == 'some expected result'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pytest.main()
```

`pytest --executable=newpath/app -s` will work fine, but it is an ugly hack. More importantly, it ran a test which was not doing any actual testing.  It is also problematic as the argument is not an optional. Without setting --executable. The path will be an `NoneType` rather than the original default path .

Any suggestion please?

Appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need global vars, just use the `request` fixture as test argument to get access to the command line arg, like you already have in `pass_executable`. This is how I would change both tests:

```
def test_1(request):
    cmd = [request.config.getoption("--executable")]
    stdout, stderr = run_subprocess(cmd)
    assert stdout == 'some expected result'


@pytest.mark.parametrize("arg", [1, 2, 3])
def test_2(request, arg):
    cmd = paramparser(request.config.getoption("--executable"), arg)
    stdout, stderr = run_subprocess(cmd)
    assert stdout == 'some expected result'
```

If you don't like the code duplication in both tests, extract it into a fixture and use it as a test argument, just like the built-in `request`:

```
@pytest.fixture
def executable(request):
    return request.config.getoption("--executable")


def test_1(executable):
    cmd = [executable]
    stdout, stderr = run_subprocess(cmd)
    assert stdout == 'some expected result'


@pytest.mark.parametrize("arg", [1, 2, 3])
def test_2(executable, arg):
    cmd = paramparser(executable, arg)
    stdout, stderr = run_subprocess(cmd)
    assert stdout == 'some expected result'
```

Comment: This is great. Thank you !

Comment: Glad I could help!